# increase ListFragment inbuilt empty text view size

Tags: android, textview, android-listfragment

I m using listfragment in my app. When the data fails to load I call setEmptyText with the failure message. This works fine on 4 inch phones but on 7 and 10 inch phones the size of the empty textview is very small and hard to read.

4 inch empty text view

[image]

7 inch empty text view

[image]

How can I increase the size of empty text view?

Comment: You could either look for that `TextView` using the id `android.R.id.empty` or, much better, implement the `ListFragment` view to contain a `ListView` plus the empty view, a centered `TextView`(with the id `anddroid:id/empty`) to which you could set directly the dimens value(with different folder values).

Comment: yeah, that is what I ll do if I can't find any other solution. Thanks

Comment: The 'empty view' is actually associated with the `ListView` (or more precise: the `AdapterView`), and not the `ListFragment`. As such, you can call [`getListView().getEmptyView()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.html#getEmptyView%28%29) in the fragment to get a handle on it. By default the empty view is a plain `TextView`, so after a cast you could apply the desired customizations.

Answer (score 4):

You can provide your own `TextView` to be used as the "empty text", it just needs to have `android:id="@id/android:empty"` and the `ListFragment` will use it instead of the standard one.

You could then customize the style of this TextView however you like (either statically in the xml layout):

```
 <TextView android:id="@id/android:empty"
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_height="match_parent"
           android:textSize="... />
```

or by calling `findViewById()` in `onCreateView()`:

```
TextView emptyTextView = (TextView)view.findViewById(android.R.id.empty);
emptyTextView.setTextSize(...);
```

A (very good) alternative, as @Delblanco commented, is to call `getListView().getEmptyView()`. It will return either the `TextView` with id `android.R.id.empty` (if supplied in the layout), or the standard `TextView` that is used otherwise.

Comment: @ShivamVerma Yes, you can compare both `ListFragment` classes and you'll see that the only practical difference is that while the framework one inflates a layout from a resource (`com.android.internal.R.layout.list_content`) the support one creates the views inline. But in both you can override and use your custom layout, and both look for `android.R.id.empty` inside.

Comment: There is another option `getListView().getEmptyView()` that way you don't need reflection and always get the view that is set as empty view.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a drop in extension for ListFragment which changes the size (and color) of the empty view programmatically:

```
/**
 * Abstract list fragment that does customizations of the list style.
 */
public abstract class LoggingListFragment extends ListFragment {

  @Override
  public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);

    TextView emptyView = null;
    View possibleEmptyView = view.findViewById(0x00ff0001);
    if (possibleEmptyView instanceof TextView) {
      emptyView = (TextView) possibleEmptyView;
    }
    if (emptyView == null) {
      possibleEmptyView = getListView().getEmptyView();
      if (possibleEmptyView instanceof TextView) {
        emptyView = (TextView) possibleEmptyView;
      }
    }
    if (emptyView != null) {
      emptyView.setTextColor(getActivity().getResources().getColor(R.color.list_subtitle_normal));
      emptyView.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 17);
    }
    return view;
  }

}
```

Comment: thanks works for me and one question from where you get this ID `0x00ff0001`?

Answer (score 0):

1. Create different folders like res/values-sw720dp,res/values-sw600dp,
   res/values-v11.
2. Create dimen.xml with different font size of different screen size.
3. Use values/dimen.xml:

   <resources>
   <dimen name="normal_font">16sp  </dimen>
     </resources>

4.Use in your widget in your xml.

android:textSize="@dimen/normal_font

Comment: I know about different value folder for different layout, but my problem is getting a reference to the empty text view in list fragment on which I can call setTextSize()

Answer (score 0):

I would do it a bit differently.

My idea: find out the dimensions of the screen and use a switch/case statement to adjust your textView text's size.

For example:

```
    switch ( area ) {
      case 7inch: 
        TextView emptyTextView = (TextView)view.findViewById(android.R.id.empty);
        emptyTextView.setTextSize(...);
      break;
      case 4inch: 
       TextView emptyTextView = (TextView)view.findViewById(android.R.id.empty);
       emptyTextView.setTextSize(...);
      break;
      default:
        values_not_caught_above;

    }
```

You can find the dimensions of the screen as follows:

If you want the display dimensions in pixels you can use [getSize](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/Display.html#getSize%28android.graphics.Point%29):

```
Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
Point size = new Point();
display.getSize(size);
int width = size.x;
int height = size.y;
int area = height*width;
```

If you're not in an `Activity` you can get the default Display via WINDOW_SERVICE:

```
WindowManager wm = (WindowManager) context.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
Display display = wm.getDefaultDisplay();
```

Before `getSize` was introduced (in API level 13), you could use the `getWidth` and `getHeight` methods that are now deprecated:

```
Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay(); 
int width = display.getWidth();  // deprecated
int height = display.getHeight();  // deprecated
```

I like my way best because it's very easy to just add another case statement for an additional device(may be 10inch screen). Almost nothing in your code will need to change that way.

Comment: Be careful, as those sizes are in _pixels_, so they will tell you very little about the physical dimensions of the screen. Compare for example a Nexus 5 (1920×1080) with a Galaxy Tab 10.1 (1280×800).

Answer (score 0):

You may increase the size of the text by calling `setEmptyText` method with a `Spannable`, let me show you some code:

```
String yourEmptyTextMessage = getString(R.string.yourEmptyTextMessage);
Spannable spanText = new SpannableString(yourEmptyTextMessage);
spanText.setSpan(new RelativeSizeSpan(1.5f), 0, yourEmptyTextMessage.length(), 0);
setEmptyText(spanText)
```

You may want to change `1.5f`  multiplier value to desired ratio